# What is the equivalent of Mage::app() in magento 2, like Magento 1?

Tags: magento2

I am `Migrating a website` from **Magento 1** to **Magento 2**. In **Magento 1**, I was using

```
<?php $isReviewScreen = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'review'; ?>
```

I am trying to get the equivalent of this code in **magento 2**? Please help me to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Please let me know if you have any issue

Comment: can i use <?php  $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();?> for this?

Comment: @Yudi you can get it directly then why are you using object manager?

Comment: @QaisarSatti i am not getting you properly. Can you please tell me how can i get it directly ? thanks for your quick reply

Comment: @Yudi `$this->getRequest()->getRouteName();` as it is mention in link answers

Comment: @QaisarSatti Can i use it inside my phtml file which is in Magento_catalog..?

Comment: @Yudi yes it is mention in answer that are for both `phtml` and `controller`.

Comment: You can directly call $this->getRequest()->getRouteName(), Below way is for using block file and also used in observer file.

Comment: What is the issue you have faced? please let me know?

Answer (score 3):

you can get directly in **controller**

```
$this->getRequest()->getRouteName();
```

or **phtml** file

```
$this->getRequest()->getRouteName();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_request = $request;
        parent::__construct($data);
    }

public function getroute(){
    $this->_request->getRouteName();
 }
```

You can also get Controller name, action name using below method in template file directly,

```
$this->getRequest()->getRouteName(),
$this->getRequest()->getControllerName(),
$this->getRequest()->getActionName(),
```

**If you want to get inside Observer file you have to create `__construct()` method and set RequestInterface.**